# Sencha Native app with settings

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2, appsettings

I am developing native app for iOS with Sencha Touch and PhoneGap. Everything is working fine. I need to facilitate users to change the application settings like in Facebook app and gmail app's setting. This is for user personalisation.

How is it possible either in Sencha Touch or PhoneGap or any other options to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Sencha perspective, you probably just need an [`Ext.form.Panel`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel) to present the user the choices.

Then you could use the form [`submit()`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-submit) method to post them to a remote server, or the [`getValues()`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-getValues) method to retrieve the values and store them locally using one of the methods provided by Cordova/Phonegap [Storage](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) API.

Comment: Thank you. I am fine with your solution.